# How I can change Combo Box value from another Combo Box using VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to change combo box value based on other combo box selection. 
Please see below the code:

```
 Private Sub combo1_AfterUpdate()



      If (Me.combo1.Value = "MHE") Then
        Me.Combo2.Value = "SELECT * FROM Table1"

      End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've posted?

Comment: @Ken White, I have created to tables with different data s and I want to change combo box value from another combo box.Example: When I will select value MHE in the first combo, I want the other combo to select data's from Table1.When I will select something else, the other combo will select data's from Table2. How this can be done using VBA?

Comment: You're not doing that; you're assigning a string containing SQL (not the results of running that SQL statement). Do the select, iterate through the results, and `Add()` them to the combobox. There are literally hundreds (if not more) examples of retrieving data from a query here; search for them. A quick search for `[access-vba] combobox from database` turned up [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22753894/62576) in about 1/2 a second.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Rowsource of the combobox

```
If (Me.combo1.Value = "MHE") Then
  Me.Combo2.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM Table1"
  Me.Combo2.Requery
End If
```

Comment: did you set the RowSourceType to Table/Query?

Comment: Yes, exactly how you have explained

Comment: Try to eliminate all other possible sources of error: To test it, first use two buttons which change the rowsource to table1 and table2 respectively.

Comment: ... and set the initial rowsource (in inspector at designtime) to table1. The part thats relevant to your question (Rowsource = "SELECT..:" works. Really. There are probably thousands of developers that have used that exact pattern - so the fact that yours doesn't work lies somewhere else...